# SimpleDateFormat not parsing time correctly

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java-time

This is happening with one (probably more) datetime where the time part is totally wrong in a parse.

The code:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestTimeParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFmt = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.getDefault());
        dateFmt.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date date = dateFmt.parse("2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z", pos);
        System.out.println("Text 2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z parses as " + date);
    }
}
```

The output:

> Text 2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z parses as Thu Nov 01 20:00:00 MDT
>   2018

What is going on for the time component? The hours is wrong and the minutes & seconds are zeroed out.

Comment: Changing the pattern to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` and the input to `"2018-11-01T18:07:55.672Z"` seems to take the problem away. Not sure if it's a bug related to the subseconds value...

Comment: If I may... **Most** of the times, people writing a date format parser with a pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'` are actually trying to parse a ISO-8601 date(time). And using such a fixed, string based, timezone unaware pattern is a **terrible idea** to parse ISO 8601 dates. So if it is actually what you are trying to do, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: java.util.Date can only handle milliseconds. So, the only supported pattern by SimpleDateFormat for this is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", which means you dates must also be represented with milliseconds.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree. Unfortunately this is code that was written before java 1.8 and we need to refactor it. But in the meantime, we need to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [one of the problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) with the obsolete `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. You shouldn't use it, for it's supplanted by the new Date and Time API in Java 8. It is available in the `java.time` package.

```
String str = "2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'";

LocalDateTime ts = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
System.out.println("Text 2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z parses as " + ts);
```

---

It seems that SimpleDateFormat is only able to read up to three millisecond digits. The parsing process works if one truncates the fraction portion of the date to three digits, i.e. "2018-11-01T18:07:55.672" instead of "2018-11-01T18:07:55.6725292Z", and also changes the according 'S' pattern specifiers, i.e. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the exact problem is? The old API is known to work in most cases. Why doesn't work here?

Comment: I think the issue is that SimpleDateFormat has resolution only down to the millisecond. You are specifying a precision much higher than the three digits available (000-999 ms). The SimpleDateFormat may be getting confused with the out of bound condition.

Comment: @ernest_k 6725292 milliseconds equals 1 hour 52 minutes 5.292 seconds. Add these to the time, 18:07:55, to obtain — yes, 20:00:00.292 to be precise — rendered as 20:00:00 since milliseconds are not printed.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for solving the mystery. I didn't get it

Comment: MC Emperor Better and simpler without any explicit formatter: Either just `Instant.parse(str)` or just `OffsetDateTime.parse(str)`. This works because the format is the standard ISO 8601.

Comment: Yes, the terrible legacy classes (`Date`, `Calendar`) were limited to a resolution of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). In a stroke of amazingly bad design, the awful legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp` bolts on a place to hold nanoseconds while maintaining the milliseconds as well, by inheriting from `java.util.Date`. Yet another of *many* reasons to **never use the legacy date-time classes**. In contrast, the *java.time* classes neatly use [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution consistently.